# is there an easy way to use theme colors in react-autosuggest items

Tags: material-ui, autosuggest

I'm trying to use react-autosuggest as it is designed to be, for me, the method signature of **renderSuggestion** should contain the actual theme, so we can use variables from the theme in our styling

Here's my workaround, but I just want to be sure I'm not making something uselessly complex:

```
                                        <AutoSuggest
                                                renderSuggestion={createRenderSuggestion(this.props.classes)}
/>
```

the variable **this.props.classes** is populated at the component creation

```
withStyles(styles)(ShopSuggestBox)
```

an I had to define a method within a method to get access to the actual **theme**

```
const createRenderSuggestion = theme => suggestion => {
    console.log("setting css of name:", theme.itemName)
    return (
            <div>
                <div className={theme.itemName}>
                    {suggestion.name}
                </div>
                <div className={theme.itemInfo}>
                    NYC
                </div>
            </div>
    )
}
```

Just to be sure to be clear: when I attempt to access to the theme within the method **[function renderSuggestion(suggestion, { query, isHighlighted })](https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest#renderSuggestionProp)** i can't

Comment: @moroshko i didn't find a tag for react-autosuggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component.

You could also use `withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(ShopSuggestBox);` if you don't want to compose.

Either way the `theme` is then accessible in the props of you `ShopSuggestBox`.

Comment: Hi @epsilon, thanks for the answer. It's true that now that I added withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true }), the theme became available in the props. The issue is that it didn't include the new styles I passed as a parameter to withStyles. Is it that is only overrides existing styles???

Comment: The styles in `withStyles(styles)` are available in `props.classes`. Remember those are only classnames not the actual style object. If you need inline styles you don't have to use `withStyles`

Comment: p.s: in the doc you pointed me to there's info about withTheme, I looked at the doc of withStyles, and I didn't see the {withTheme: true } option : https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-withstyles

I think it's a confusing documentation as a new comer in material since there are described problems but no recommended best practices

Comment: thanks it worked when using props.classes, I found my attributes. Unfortunaletely for me, it's still not clear why these attributes are not inserted to the style object (is it to avoid the style to be spread on the entire app?): in my naive thoughts, I imagined the style object reconstructed with overriden values and added attributes as a result of a withStyles call. I see I was wrong, but why?

Comment: @ZiedHamdi I thing every question ins answered throughout https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/ The section you linked is specific to typescript. It is not meant as a full documentation of withStyles

Comment: Ok thanks, I still didn't get to read the customization section, mea culpa :)